# Android How to stop database insertion process

Tags: android, sqlite

My app stores large amount of user data in local database, like use name password, user file, images etc by **IntentService** which calls several web services, every thing is working well. 
My problem is if new user logs in, while the IntentService is still running I am unable to delete the old user data the log says **Data Base locked**. 
How to stop IntentService and delete database to replace with new user data.

**EDIT**

I followed [this](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-using-databaseutils-inserthelper-for-faster-insertions-into-sqlite-database/) for insertion.

Comment: seems like you can post your code segment which handles the data base insertion

Answer (score 0):

when you want to change the data.. broadcast an intent..like this

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext());
intent.setAction("com.toxy.Edit");
intent.putExtra("work","Editing");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

in the onrecieve of the receiver

```
 @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

            String w = arg1.getExtras().getString("work");

       if(w=="Editing")
       {
          //pause the intent service here.. 
        }
```

refer this question to pause.. [How to stop an IntentService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503244/how-to-stop-an-intentservice)
      else{

```
        //resume the intent service...
       }

     }
```